# Maven jboss-as:run with standalone-full.xml

Tags: maven, jboss7.x

I am starting jboss 7.2 from eclipse using the goal jboss-as:run but it is starting with the default standalone.xml configuraiton. I want to start it with the standalone-full.xml.

What parameter/configuration should I use.

https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/run-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

```
               <jboss-as.serverConfig>standalone-full.xml</jboss-as.serverConfig>
```

I kept this property in pom.xml